# action is always return null

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

My action  is :

```
[HttpPost]
public ViewResult SearchPost(FormCollection frm)
{

    IList <post> p =db.posts.Include("user").ToList();


    if (Request.Form["area"] != null)          
    {
        if ((p!=null) && (p.Any()))

        {

            p =p.Where(a=>a.area==Request.Form["area"]).ToList();     

        }
   }           
    if (Request.Form["floor"] != null)          
    {              
        if ((p!=null) && (p.Any()))

        {
            p = p.Where(a => a.floor ==   
           Request.Form["floor"]).ToList();                              
        }
    }            
    if (Request.Form["garage"] != null)          
    {
        if ((p!=null) && (p.Any()))

        {
            p = p.Where(a => a.garage ==   
            Request.Form["garage"]).ToList();                                    
        }
    }  


    return View(p);
}
```

it has shown no errors. but always return null. it should return filtered post objects or simply all posts without filtering. is there any problem ?? i can't find it .

Comment: I see no way this could possibly return `null` for the view data; `p` is assigned on every path.  It might be an empty list, but not `null`. Do you mean something else, then?

Comment: Is db.posts.Include("user").ToList() always null? Thats the only way I can see it would return null.

Comment: @Gage `ToList` never returns null. Unless they defined their own ToList, which seems unlikely

Comment: Did you debug to see whats the value of p before return?

Comment: Why dont you use lazy loading of linq? Why dont you do someting like `var p =db.posts.Include("user");` and all other places when you deal with p? Just make `ToList()` when returning.

Comment: actually in the view model i use **@model IEnumerable<ToLet.Models.DB.post>** when i call the action by GETPOST  it returns all the data of DB.post type. it works fine. but when i  sends HTTPPOST with some search criteria then above action is called.after this always it returns nothing(no data).i think it sends empty p.but according my DB it should sends some data..

Comment: Is there any Problem in IList<post> type??? should i return a var type???  **var p =db.posts.Include("user").ToList();**
instead of **IList <post> p =db.posts.Include("user").ToList();**

Comment: I've check by p.count()<1 . this condition get always true even i didn't enter any selection criteria!!! i don't understand why it is happening !!!!

Comment: The "var" change will make no difference.  Besides that, it's very hard to tell what problem you're actually having.  Please think about it more and try a more focused question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the full signatures of the types that you are dealing with, but perhaps try this code and see if you get any better results:

```
[HttpPost]
public ViewResult SearchPost(FormCollection frm)
{
    var area = Request.Form["area"];
    var floor = Request.Form["floor"];
    var garage = Request.Form["garage"];

    return View(db.posts.Include("user")
        .Where(a => area == null || a.area == area)
        .Where(a => floor == null || a.floor == floor)
        .Where(a => garage == null || a.garage == garage).ToList());
}
```

(This is essentially a rewrite of your code down into a single query that might help you with debugging.)